# javascript window.location gives me a wrong url path when checking firebug

Tags: javascript

I have a sample url website: http://mysite.com/

```
 var host = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.hostname;

$.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   data: params,
   url : host+'/forms/get_data.php',
   success:function(data){
       ...othercodeblahblah
   }
});
```

Why is it that when I try to check my firebug it makes the URL weird.

This is the sample output of firebug:

```
http://mysite.com/mysite.com/forms/get_data.php
```

With this url it now gives me:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found -  http://mysite.com/mysite.com/forms/get_data.php"
```

Shouldn't it output like http://mysite.com/forms/get_data.php ?
Why is it giving me a wrong url path?

Your help would be greatly appreciated and rewarded!

Thank!

Comment: You add '://' to the `host`. `location.host` returns `http:` for me, so the `:` part may be useless. *Could* be the cause.

Comment: I already added that one too, but still it ain't working.

Comment: Do you have a working example we can test? A [fiddle](http://JSFiddle.net) would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is `window.location.protocol` already includes a colon (:).

The `host` variable therefor contains `http:://mysite.com`

jQuery picks up that you didn't pass a full valid URL, so it prepends your hostname automatically.

The fix is changing

```
var host = window.location.protocol+"://"+window.location.hostname;
```

to

```
var host = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.hostname;
```

---

### Edit

I created a jsfiddle with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/xH5ZV/

and the fixed code: http://jsfiddle.net/xH5ZV/1/

Notice in the fixed code you don't get the hostname twice.

Comment: Umm, that still didn't solved the problem, It still has that weird URL

Comment: Seems to be working for me. I edited the answer to include jsfiddle examples.

Comment: This is weird, this is what I did and seems it's working http://jsfiddle.net/spCz3/ , but i'm not satisfied!

Comment: I tried my same technique on your jsfiddle example and updated it. Works there too: http://jsfiddle.net/spCz3/1/

Comment: How to run your code there at jsfiddle? I pressed the run button but I don't know what to expect. :-)

Comment: Just look in Firebug. You can see that the hostname is not printed twice on the 404 error on the fixed example.

Comment: Right, It really works. But why is it on my site it still doubles up unless I use this code http://jsfiddle.net/spCz3/ HMPF!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure where such an error might come from, but specifying the host is redundant: AJAX requests are same-domain anyway (unless specifically configured), so just specify a part from the root:

```
url: "/forms/get_data.php",
```

Comment: I think by using that one it will give us a problem on a url that was htaccesed modifed, say for example: http://mysite.com/users/johndoe/, That would give us a jquery ajax post request of http://mysite.com/users/forms/get_data.php, wherein I don't have a folder of /users/ because what I have is http://mysite/forms/get_data.php

Comment: That's what the `/` at the start is for: to make the path relative to the entire domain.